# How to use RestKit to invoke a Webservice

Tags: ios, restkit

I am developing an application for ios . In that am need to use RestKit framework so i integrated it using CocoaPods but while invoking a webservice am unable to get how to do. Example i have a webservice url like http://dev.api.sample.com/services/v1/ and the path to add user is users/add for this i need to sent parameters in json format and i will get some data in json format and the request method is PUT. if any one know hoe to use please let me know.
I tried in this way :

```
 NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.api.sample.com/services/v1/"];
    AFHTTPClient *client1 = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [objectManager setHTTPClient:client1];
    [objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/json"];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:self method:RKRequestMethodPUT path:@"users/add" parameters:data];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
        NSLog(@"success");
        // success is called, but the result does not contain what the response JSON is
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // failure
        NSLog(@"fail");
    }];

    [operation start];
```

but am unable to get any responsse for above example.

Comment: log and check mappingResult.array values.

Comment: That is what am saying even i am not getting a log with either success or failure.

Comment: Does `objectManager` exist? Show your request and response descriptors. Turn on trace logging.